# Please help correct this cursor SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

```
 DECLARE @abc varchar(MAX);
 DECLARE @useIPDTaskDeadline INT = 1;

 DECLARE TOCREATETASKCURSOR CURSOR FOR      
       WITH TOTALTASK AS (
            SELECT  abc FROM table1
       )
       SELECT abc FROM TOTALTASK

FOR READ ONLY

OPEN TOCREATETASKCURSOR
FETCH TOCREATETASKCURSOR INTO @abc

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN -- @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    PRINT ''

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 1) 
        PRINT 'Updates completed';
END

IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 0) 
    PRINT 'Updates completed';
END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    FETCH TOCREATETASKCURSOR INTO @abc
END -- @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

CLOSE TOCREATETASKCURSOR
DEALLOCATE TOCREATETASKCURSOR
```

This throws errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 117
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CLOSE'.

Please tell me what is incorrect ? I have tried a lot but cannot make it to work. Is there any issue with IF else syntax ? I am using SQL Server.

I have tried many if else syntaxes but cannot make it work.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Updates completed';
END
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 0)
BEGIN
 PRINT 'Updates completed';
END
```

Issue is with your If You are not using **BEGIN** ,**END** Properly

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `END` statements after your `IF` blocks (or add `BEGIN` statements):

```
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 1) 
    PRINT 'Updates completed';
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 0) 
    PRINT 'Updates completed';
```

or

```
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Updates completed';
END
IF (@useIPDTaskDeadline = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Updates completed';
END
```